# Geometric Series Probability

Tags: probability

I've started working through a probability textbook and I'm unsure how it went to the next step, from the geometric series to $1-(1-p)^{n-1}$.

> $$\begin{align}
> &=p\left[\frac{1-(1-p)^{n-1}}{1-(1-p}\right]+(1-p)^{n-1}\\
> &=1-(1-p)^{n-1}+(1-p)^{n-1}
> \end{align}$$

I thought about multiplying by the conjugate but unsure if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing the fact $1-(1-p) = p$ and it cancels with the $p$ outside the bracket?

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Yeah. I was totally missing that. I thought it would be more complicated.